# Can 5630 SMD on LED strips be RGB?

Tags: led, surface-mount, rgb

Hi I've been trying to look online for RGB 5630 LEDs strips but I can't find any. All the strips I've found carried 5050s which give a max of 1020 lm/m more or less..

Any idea if strips carrying 5630s cannot be RGB for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

5630 leds are two pin packages. You will not find an addressable or manual rgb led in a 2 pin package. You could find a strip that has 3 5630 leds right next to each other to provide the RGB, but it won't look as nice and probably isn't a mass produced led strip.